# Mysql 1064(4200) error shows up when I tried to create a table

Tags: mysql

```
-CREATE TABLE accesslogs (
page VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
userid VARCHAR(8) BINARY NOT NULL,
visitcount MEDIUMINT(5) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
accessdate TIMESTAMP(14),
PRIMARY KEY (userid, page));
```

After I press enter from the command line and error is shown:

```
-ERROR 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14), PRIMARY KEY (userid, page)'
at line 5.
```

This error keeps on occurring every time I try to create the table after flushing the privileges.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version ..."

Comment: The error is very clear: you can't put `(14)` after `TIMESTAMP`. What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
accessdate TIMESTAMP(14),
```

to

```
accessdate TIMESTAMP,
```

The `TIMESTAMP` data type doesn't have a size option.